# closeOnCompletion() method is not supported by HANA Cloud JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis, hana

I use the cursor of MyBatis to accept the search results from HANA:

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface XXXRepository {
    org.apache.itatis.cursor.Cursor<XXXEntity> getData();
}
```

but got an error:

```
Cause: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLFeatureNotSupportedExceptionSapDB: Method closeOnCompletion() of Statement is not supported.
  ; Method closeOnCompletion() of Statement is not supported.
  ; nested exception is com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLFeatureNotSupportedExceptionSapDB: 
    Method closeOnCompletion() of Statement is not supported.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:96)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:88)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.selectCursor(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectCursor(SqlSessionTemplate.java:199)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForCursor(MapperMethod.java:167)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:84)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy251.getReqSlipPrintCount(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy252.getReqSlipPrintCount(Unknown Source)
```

Is the cursor of MyBatis not supported by HANA?

The JDBC which I use is `com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc:ngdbc:2.11.14`.

Comment: SAP HANA driver does not seem to support `Statement#closeOnCompletion()` even in the latest version (2.15.10), so unfortunately, you cannot use MyBatis' Cursor with it. BTW, SAP ASE's JDBC driver (jconn42.jar) supports `closeOnCompletion()`.

Comment: You have indicated "SapDB" which is an old SAP database now named SAP MaxDB which is not much used. I guess you mean SAP HANA so I replaced the term. Please correct it if needed and argument how MaxDB is related to your HANA issue.

Comment: Note that JDBC drivers are required to support this; it is not an optional method, so it is not allowed to throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. You should report a bug to SAP that they must fix this.